# Change method from dll C#

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, avalondock

I'm using avalondock 2.0 dll in my solution and I need to change `IOverlayWindowHost.GetDropAreas` method from [DockingManager.cs](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/DockingManager.cs) at another project.
But, I don't want to do this at the source file. The method is not virtual and I can't just override it like this

```
class CustomDockingManager : DockingManager
{
     override IEnumerable<IDropArea> GetDropAreas(LayoutFloatingWindowControl draggingWindow)
     {
          //some changes
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do *IL weaving* to change a non-virtual method. You've many options here.

- [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/). Check this other Q&A that might give you some direction on how to solve your issue: [C# Intercept/change/redirect a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081773/c-sharp-intercept-change-redirect-a-method)
- [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/). If you just want to add some code before and after some method execution, PostSharp makes it easier than emitting intermediate language *by hand*. You would do it using an `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` attribute. See this article to get in touch with method aspects: http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Day-4-OnMethodBoundaryAspect

Answer (score 2):

Although not recommended in general, you can use the C# ability to reimplement explicitly just a single method of an interface, like this

```
class CustomDockingManager : DockingManager, IOverlayWindowHost
{
    IEnumerable<IDropArea> IOverlayWindowHost.GetDropAreas(LayoutFloatingWindowControl draggingWindow)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that this way you cannot use the base implementation, you have to write the method from scratch.